# Skipping in dance videos

Tags: video

Dance videos are distinct from other videos in that you often want to rewind and play parts back many times for practice. I need a web application that will allow me to host a video and add bookmarks to make playback easier. Additionally, if I am bookmarking each move, many of the bookmarks will be only a second or two apart. Is there any web application that will allow me to do that easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/) - it allows to [link at specific time](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=116618). You can create multiple bookmarks to allow you to replay it from specific time. There is also a [webapp](http://youtubetime.com/) that helps you create those urls.

It allows you to create play lists and in case you are using Google Chrome - there is [an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kanbnempkjnhadplbfgdaagijdbdbjeb) that allows you to replay your video from specific time.

Comment: I suppose adding a whole list of links to the comments works